# Combining Three Arrays in foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I know how to combine two arrays in foreach loop using `array_combine()` function of PHP

But I have three arrays and I want to loop through all of three arrays at a time.

```
$get_id=$data->get_id;
$get_product=$data->get_product;
$get_comment=$data->get_comment;

foreach (array_combine($get_id, $get_product) as $id => $product) {
    echo "$id - $product<br/>";

}
```

I want to iterate `$get_comment` array too in this loop.

Thanks

Comment: If these arrays are numerically indexed, you could use a `for` loop.

Comment: These arrays are having random values from ajax JSON request

Comment: Not concerned about the values for the time being but the keys assigned to these values... What about the keys... Are they assigned by you or system generated (or as pointed by @AmalMurali) / numerically indexed.

Comment: @explorecode: I'm talking about their keys, not values. Can you show the `print_r()` outputs of the array?

Comment: But how will i get the nth positions of these arrays. And Yes all them  will having same size

Comment: @AmalMurali ok let me check

Comment: @AmalMurali echo and print_r() giving same output

Comment: @explorecode That's only possible if you're printing a string / integer. Are you sure it *is* an array? What does `var_dump()` say?

Comment: @AmalMurali `string (10) "value1"` ...

Comment: I am fetching data from $ajax using `$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);`

Comment: @explorecode: Can you please edit the question to include all the **relevant** details and explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
$get_id=$data->get_id;
$get_product=$data->get_product;
$get_comment=$data->get_comment;

foreach($get_id as $i => $id){
    $product = $get_product[$i];
    $comment = $get_comment[$i];
    echo "$id , $product, $comment<br/>";
}
```

This solution assumes the $get_id, $get_product, and $get_comment arrays are all indexed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the arrays before the foreach loop

```
    $comment_array = array_combine($get_id, $get_comment);
    $product_array = array_combine($get_id, $get_product);
    foreach ($product_array as $id => $product) {
      $comment = $comment_array[$id];
    }
```

Comment: Will it work because `$get_id` contains alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem,  all arrays in PHP are associative.