# wanted to use foreach loop for 3 arrays combined in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" class="checkbox-input" name="challan[]" >

<input type="text"  name='tds[]' class="form-control" onkeyup='tambah();'   >             
                                              
<input type="text"  name='suspense[]' onkeyup='tambah();'  class="form-control" >
```

Getting values from 3 arrays using form

array1 - Invoice no.s
array2 - amount to be deducted under tds for each invoice no.
array3 - amount to be deducated under suspense for each invoice no.

I want to update tds value and suspense value for each challanno in array challan

```
$challan = explode(',', $challan);
$tds = explode(',', $tds);
$suspense=explode(',',$suspense); 
 foreach ($challan as $n ) {
 foreach (array_combine($tds, $suspense) as $t => $s) {
//update query
}}
```

Tried the above code but same $tds & $suspense value updated on every record.

Usually for two arrays i use array_combile as given below.

```
foreach (array_combine($challan2, $tds2) as $n => $t) {

}
```

Help me solve the issue

Comment: Why not demonstrate your data arrays. Visualize what your data is, and then how you want to process them to be. And what are you trying with your code. Thats the way to make a question well-efforted. Your answers would be more involved if you state all your phases well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining Three Arrays in foreach loop in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227658/combining-three-arrays-in-foreach-loop-in-php)

Comment: @Lenin updated the question pls check

Comment: You gave 3 html input fields. Rathe just put in your possible array data. And how your output would look like. Thats what would help you get quicker answers. Because people are busy in their own life too.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it looks like you have multiple issues, you are combining 2 arrays as `key => value` but those keys and values aren't unique, also if they are different lengths it will throw an error, I'd think back to what you are trying to achieve and see if there is a better way

Comment: @lenin - thanks this helped - foreach($challan2 as $i => $n){
    $t = $tds2[$i];
    $s = $suspense2[$i];
    echo "$n , $t, $s<br/>";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps

```
 foreach($challan2 as $i => $n){ 
     $t = $tds2[$i]; 
     $s = $suspense2[$i]; 
     echo "$n , $t, $s<br/>";
 }
```